# PHONE_MIGRATE_X error in using TLsharp for Telegram Programming

Tags: c#, api, telegram

I started using TLSharp in C# for Telegram. When I'm authenticating the user with this function:

```
public async Task AuthUser()
{
   var store = new FileSessionStore();
   var client = new TelegramClient(store, "session");

   await client.Connect();

   var hash = await client.SendCodeRequest(NumberToAuthenticate);
   var code = "123"; // you can change code in debugger

   var user = await client.MakeAuth(NumberToAuthenticate, hash, code);

   Assert.IsNotNull(user);
}
```

On `SendCodeRequest` to my phone number I get the `PHONE_MIGRATE_4` error. How could I fix that?

Telegram website for this error says that I need to switch my data centre. How can I do this in TLsharp?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used the TLSharp but according to its documentation you need to update the data centre address in `TLSharp.Core.Network.TcpTransport.cs`, a file provided by TLSharp library.

According to its [documentation][1]:

```
I get an error MIGRATE_X?

You should change the telegram server address to X. X server address you can get from InitResponse or from Server addresses list. Address should be changed in `TLSharp.Core.Network.TcpTransport.cs`

Server addresses:

    Server 1: 149.154.175.50:443
    Server 2: 149.154.167.51:443
    Server 3: 149.154.175.100:443
    Server 4: 149.154.167.91:443
    Server 5: 91.108.56.165:443
```

Default server address used in `TLSharp.Core.Network.TcpTransport.cs` is `91.108.56.165` ie `server 5`.
[1]: https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp#i-get-an-error-migrate_x

Answer (score 0):

When you send help.getNearestDC, you should get the proper DC to use.

You will get MIGRATE_X if the number you are trying to authenticate is on a different DataCenter than the one you are currently using.